# Is there a way I can turn on apc.rfc1867 for just one page?

Tags: apc, php, configure

apc.rfc1867 local & master is set to "off".
Can I enable it just at the top of one page?

Comment: Why not just avoid adding the `APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS` field to that page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation on [apc.rfc1867](http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php), no, you cannot disable this on a per-page or user-script basis, as it is changeable in the `PHP_INI_SYSTEM` category, which corresponds to: `Entry can be set in php.ini or httpd.conf`

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the .ini setting in an Apache  [`<Files>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files) directive, so it's set for only that one file. If you need multiple files, multiple files directives can be enabled. This can also be done in a .htaccess (or within a `<Directory>` directive) so it can be made to apply only to certain subdirectories

```
<Files "enabled_for_just_this_file.php">
  php_value apc.rfc1867 "1"
</Files>
```